# is cheese safe to eat when the refrigerator was 57 degrees

Tags: cheese

soft and hard cheeses were left overnight in the refrigerator with the door was a bit open and the temperature was at 57degrees in the morning . Is the cheese safe to eat?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, cheese is a very resilient food. That's why it was invented/discovered: to enable people to have the benefits of milk without the perishability. According to   http://www.cheesemaking.com/learn/how-to/make-a-cheese-cave.html    ...

how you want to age your cheese is at "A proper and as constant Temperature (45-58F) as possible", so assuming you are talking about Fahrenheit (ha-ha.), that's an OK temperature for cheese (even for extended periods like aging). Keeping it at colder, refrigerator temps is better for slowing down unwanted mold development, but 57 degrees F, *overnight*: it's fine.

Not sure about the rest of the refrigerator contents though, like the milk maybe.